# How to save customer in database after billing info step on onepage checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, customer-address, billing-address

I would like to save customer in database, when someone filled billing information and hit the 'continue' button. Does anyone know how to do it?

I am using magento 1.9.2 and i tried with event "controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling" but its not working over there, nothing happen with event or observer.

After saving customer in database i would like to logged in with that customer id, and need to refresh the page, or any other way is welcomed.

I would like to know how to do this ? if any idea please share here.

code as below :

> create Utsav_Customersave.xml in app/etc/modules/

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Utsav_Customersave>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Utsav_Customersave>
</modules>`

> in app/code/local/Utsav/Customersave/etc/config.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Utsav_Customersave>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Utsav_Customersave>
</modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_address_save_after>
            <observers>
                <auto_register_shipping>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Utsav_Customersave_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>autoRegisterBilling</method>
                </auto_register_shipping>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_address_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
</config>`

> in app/code/local/Utsav/Customersave/Model/Observer.php

`<?php
class Utsav_Customersave_Model_Observer {

    public function autoRegisterBilling($evt){
        if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
            $data = $evt->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
            $email = $data['email'];
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
            $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
            $pwd = $data['customer_password'];
            $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())->loadByEmail($email);

            if (!$customer->getId()) {
                 //Code begins here for new customer registration
                $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
                $customer->setStore($store);
                $customer->firstname = $data['firstname'];
                $customer->lastname = $data['lastname'];
                $customer->setEmail($email);
                $customer->setPassword($pwd);
                $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('confirmed');  
                $customer->save();
                   }
           }
    }
}`

Comment: try the even **sales_quote_address_save_after**

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but i tried with this below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939733/customer-save-beore-process-checkout-button-click but nothing happen. as you suggested for "sales_quote_address_save_after" instead of "controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling" should i directly use your given event ?

Comment: yes , you can use directly.

Comment: put your code that is used

Comment: code aded in main post please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following code in **config.xml** and check your observer is cxecuting or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Customersave>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Customersave>
</modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
            <observers>
                <customersave>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Utsav_Customersave_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>autoRegisterBilling</method>
                </customersave>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling>
     </events>
 </global>  
</config>
```

Comment: I think that event was not firing somehow. Change the previous event as shown my edited answer.

Comment: i dont know but  :( still not working.. observer is not cxecuting.

Comment: check your module is enabled or not

Comment: module is enabled  but in 'core_resource" table there is no entry for this module, will it be there ?

Comment: No. it will not. you can try the code in default magento

Comment: did you able to debug the error?

Comment: its working now. there is one silly mistake "config" tag not closed in app/etc/modules/Utsav_Customersave.xml Thanks a lot..

Comment: if i want to save address after customer save then how could i save it ?

Comment: use **Mage::getModel("customer/address")** model